# Cannot link swf file to rfxviewer

Tags: flash

Good day,

I am stuck with this problem,
I am converting pdf files into swf file using this command in php:

```
exec("C:\\SWFTools\\pdf2swf.exe ".$source." -o ".$converted." -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters");
```

Though almost all pdf's are converting right and linked to my viewer. but, there are some pdf files that cannot be converted so I am manually doing it in the command line, I am faced with this error:

```
NOTICE  processing PDF page 9 (595x842:0:0)
ERROR   ID Table overflow
ERROR   This file is too complex to render- SWF only supports 65536 shapes at once
```

Well, I've done some research http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tools.swftools.general/2098
and tried the solution and it worked.

However my problem is this, I cannot link now this swf file into rfxviewer using this command:

```
exec("C:\\SWFTools\\swfcombine.exe -o ".$combined." C:\\SWFTools\\swfs\\rfxview.swf viewport=".$converted);
```

I've tried the cmd thing and it shows this error:

```
Warning: File contains both flash 8 and flash 9 actionscript
Warning: File contains both flash 8 and flash 9 actionscript
```

How can I link now this swf file to my viewer? Do I miss any important command? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think rfxview.swf just support flash 7 and flash 8, you need change "-T 9" to "-T 8".